# Not able to get exact meaning of self and __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written program below without using the `__init__` purposely.

```
class testing:
     skills=[]
     def addSkill(self,skill):
         self.skills.append(skill)
john=testing()
betty=testing()
john.addSkill("FOOTBALL")
betty.addSkill("TENNIS")
print john.skills
```

Above code gives the output as `['FOOTBALL', 'TENNIS']`.

Now I am not able to understand as why python is appending to the same variable `skills` even when I have created two different instances and used `self` (`self.skills.append(skill)`) to append to particular instance only.

Although if I use `__init__` and then declare the `skills` set inside it, then my code is working fine.

Comment: because `skills` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute; *it's shared among instances*.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard thanks for the answer. But then what is the use of self here.

Comment: `self` represents the instance. Through the instance you can access both instance attributes and class ones. You're accessing a class attribute through `self` and modifying it.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard then how come the below code printing JOHN instead of BETTY, as class variable name is assigned a value BETTY after the JOHN i.e the value must be overwritten during the second assignment.
    

`class testing:
    skills=[]
    name=""
    def addSkill(self,skill):
        self.skills.append(skill)


john=testing()
betty=testing()
john.name="JOHN"
betty.name="BETTY"


print john.name`